# Angular: get element within component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

Suppose I have a component like this

```
app.component('test',{
    template: '<input type="text" id="inputbox"></input>',
    controller: function() {
        ctrl.focusInput = function(){
                var inputbox = document.getElementById("inputbox");
                inputbox.focus();
            }
        };
    }    
});
```

I would like to get the DOM element for the input so I can focus it whenever I want. However `inputbox` falls in global scope which will be a problem if I use this component more than once. How can I get the DOM just for the input in this component - either by restricting scope of `inputbox` or using some other mechanism?

Comment: controller: ['$element', function($element) {

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25633139/angularjs-input-field-focus-event

Comment: @PetrAveryanov so what would the `var inputbox` line look like with your suggestion?

Comment: @Daniel_L that seems to solve the opposite problem, triggering functions on focus not focus from a function?

Comment: To avoid the ID problem, remove the ID and tag it with a class, even just a dummy empty one, and select on that using querySelector or $element. Note that in Angular 1, where we didn't have template ref vars, this was the "recommended" internal practice. In general I was told never to use IDs, use classes, even dummy ones. I hated doing it but it did solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You could inject the element that triggered the component to controller function like below:

Since `$element` is `jqLite` wrapped object, you can use jQuery DOM traversal methods like children and find to find the `input` element.

```js
angular
  .module('myApp', []);
angular
  .module('myApp').component('test', {
    template: '<input type="text" id="inputbox"></input>',
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      var ctrl = this;
      ctrl.focusInput = function() {
        $timeout(function() {
          $element.find('input').focus();
        }, 0);
      };
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <test></test>
</div>
```

Comment: this method looks ok, but i suspect that this is a good practise.
if we need DOM to make manipulations, why not isolate scope directive with all that code in link function?

answer to the question is perfect though.

Comment: This seems to fail when I test `document.activeElement===$element.children().find('input')` to determine if the input is focussed already - is that because the DOM element is wrapped in something else?

Comment: Also I'm getting undefined for `$element.children().find('input')`?

Comment: The real document has `input` nested in a `div` but still `$element.find(".myinputclass")` or `$element.find("input")` should find it right?

Comment: @SideshowBob yes you can. For presentation purpose I've shown like that

Comment: Alas for either of those I'm getting `undefined is not a function` when I try to call e.g. `$element.find('input').focus()`, or `$element.find('.inputbox').eq(0).focus()` (I have changed id to class)

Comment: Ok so I had to wrap the call to `focus` in a `$timeout()`. Not quite sure why. The DOM should have been rendered already so the focus method should be available all along...